# Any way to tell if an app is sideloaded or if it was downloaded from the store?

Tags: uwp, winjs

I have some apps I build in Visual Studio 2017 for a private windows store -- sometimes they get downloaded from the private business store, sometimes they get sideloaded. They're html/javascript winjs apps.

Is there any way to programatically check if it was sideloaded or got from the store?

Comment: There is no APIs to check whether the app was installed via Microsoft Store or sideload, you can submit this feature request to the UserVoice website:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT even if there is no direct API for that purpose, are there any other APIs that you could subvert for that purpose? For example there are Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext apis -- I'm not quite sure how to interact with them -- that potentially return different information for sideloaded vs storeloaded apps?

Comment: Perhaps this code returns something different for sideloaded apps? `let storeContext = Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext.getDefault();
    let license = await storeContext.getAppLicenseAsync();`

Comment: No, this code just gets a [StoreAppLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense) object witch just provides license info for the current app, including  trial or not and the add-on license. There is no difference between sideload and store.